# Image id not showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Take a look below code I'm trying to alert the value of `i` inside the `reader.onloadend` it's not showing properly, It's showing max value of `i`, i.e if `i` add 3 images `i` alerting only three it should show 0,1 and 3.

```
$("#files2").change(function()
{
    var src=$("#files2").val();
    if(src!="")
    {
        formdata= new FormData();
        var numfiles=this.files.length;
        var i, file, progress, size;
        for(i=0;i<numfiles;i++)
        { 
        //alert(i);
            file = this.files[i];
            size = this.files[i].size;
            name = this.files[i].name;
            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/))
            {
                if((Math.round(size))<=(1024*1024))
                {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    $("#preview").show();
                    $('#preview').html("");
                    //<img src="img/remove.png"/>
                    //style='margin-left: -16px;margin-top: -6px;'
                    alert(i);
                    reader.onloadend = function(e)
                    {

                    var image = $('<img id="im'+i+'" style="float:left; height: 150px; width: 125px; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">').attr('src',e.target.result);
                    var image1 = $('<img onclick="$(this).remove();$("#im1").remove();" style=" margin-left: -25px;margin-top: -1px;z-index: 1;position: absolute; ">').attr('src','img/remove.png');

                    $(image).appendTo('#preview');
                    $(image1).appendTo('#preview');

                    };
                    formdata.append("files2[]", file);
                    if(i==(numfiles-1))
                    {
                        $(".nextim").click(function(){
                            $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "upload.php?contactid=<?php echo $id1; ?>&postid=<?php echo $id2; ?>",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: formdata,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function(res)
                            {
                                if(res!="0")
                                    $("#info").html("Successfully Uploaded");
                                else
                                    $("#info").html("Error in upload. Retry");
                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#info").html(name+"Size limit exceeded");
                    $("#preview").hide();
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $("#info").html(name+"Not image file");
                $("#preview").hide();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $("#info").html("Select an image file");
        $("#preview").hide();
        return;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: coudl u show how variable i is initialized..??

Comment: i is never modified, why do you expect it to have different values?

Comment: 'i' is not being made available to this function. This is usually caused by the variable being initialized as a local variable and outside of the function you are working within in.

Comment: var numfiles=this.files.length;
var i, file, progress, size;
for(i=0;i<numfiles;i++)
{ 
//alert(i);
file = this.files[i];
size = this.files[i].size;
name = this.files[i].name;
if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/))

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you should be looping through the number of files that are used. Since you have not showed us how variable `i` is initialized, I tried using the name as an example. Hope this might help you :)

```
for (var count = 0; count  < files.length; count ++) {
       (function(file) {
            var name = file.name;
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function(e) {
               alert(name );
            }
        })(files[count]);
    }
```